# unapprove comments on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I have registered a custom post type and I want to unapprove comments by default on this custom post type without affecting the default posts/pages which is set to approve.

I've looked through the CODEX but I can not find anything related to what I'm trying to do.

I've found just how can I display the un-approved comments. 
Code for registering custom post type:

```
// Register Custom Post Type

function debate_post_type() {



$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Debates', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Debate', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Debate', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Debate:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Debates', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Debate', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Debate', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'New Debate', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Debate', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Debate', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search debates', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'No debates found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No debates found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'debate', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Here you can post your debates', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'debate', $args );
}
// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'debate_post_type', 0 );
```

Any suggestions on how can I do this ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include any/all current, relevant code, including registering of the CPT and any current comment handling for the CPT.

Comment: Now, what do you mean by "*unapprove comments by default on this custom post type*"?

Comment: I mean that I want the comments inside this custom post type to be unapproved.

Comment: What does that mean? Are you saying that you want all comments to posts in this CPT to be *moderated* by default? Or you want *currently approved* comments for posts in this CPT to be changed to unapproved?

Comment: I want currently approved comments for posts in this CPT to be changed to unapproved

Comment: And what functions or filters did you try, from your Codex search?

Comment: I didn't try, I just looked trough and I didn't found anything that might helped me. Maybe I didn't knew where exactly to look. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write a function that fetches all comments by comment type using [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments), then loop through them and set status using [`wp_set_comment_status()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_comment_status).

e.g.

Retrieve all comments associated with posts in the `debate` post type:

```
$debate_comments = get_comments( array( 'post_type' => 'debate', 'status' => 'approve' ) );
```

Loop through each one, and change from *approved* to *moderated*:

```
foreach( $debate_comments as $debate_comment ) {
    wp_set_comment_status( $debate_comment, 'hold' );
}
```